# What is the English equivalent of the フヒヒヒ laugh?

Tags: translation, resources

I'm trying to translate a game from Japanese to English, but I cannot figure this one out. I know a lot of different forms of laughter, but this one escapes me. I've been looking for about an hour and a half online, and still can't find an example. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Edit: I believe it is either "Tee-hee-hee", "wahahaha", or "heheheh". I just need to know which is best.

Comment: Uh, I'll go with "hehehe".

Comment: But the Fu (フ) before it, and the context in-game, indicate a sort of "inside joke", so wouldn't it be something like "tee-hee-hee", "heheh", or "wahahaha"? I'm trying to make an accurate translation, so which one of those would be better?

Comment: Oh, and the text I'm translating is "ですが、それには条件がございます… フヒヒヒ", which is "But, there are conditions for it... [laugh]"

Comment: not sure how to simulate the sound affect but it sounds like a snigger.

Comment: Unless you are asking what nuance フヒヒヒ carries, this sounds more like a question about English, not about Japanese.